# Ayuda a indentificar elemento dentro de un codigo htlm metodo xpath selenium

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

Hola amigos necesito que me ayuden con esto,,,he intentado indentificar ciertos elemento para luego imprimirlos pero no lo consigo,supongamos que tenemos el sgt codigo

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

lo que quiero es identificar Test Results,192.161.163.56:3128,ONLINE Y response time:83mls

he intentado esto sin resultados,,solo tengo resultados positivos al identificar "Y" pero solo eso

```
y=driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@id="results"]').text
x=driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='rproxy']").text
z=driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='rstatus']").text
print(x)
print(y)
print(z)
```

muchas gracias

Comment: puedses hacerlo asi: `driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div.rstatus')`

Comment: siento decirle que eso no funciona amigo

Answer (score 0):

En el ejemplo  que has mostrado puedes hacerlo de dos formas.

La más sencilla puede ser usando `.text` y `.find_element_by_id`:

```
print(driver.find_element_by_id('results').text)
```

La otra opción es un poco parecida, también usando `.find_element_by_id`:

```
results = driver.find_element_by_id('results')
#Hay 2 elementos h3, pero si usas find_element_by_tag_name, solo traerá el primero.
h3 = results.find_element_by_tag_name('h3')
print(h3.text)
proxy = results.find_element_by_class_name('rproxy')
print(proxy.text)
status= results.find_element_by_class_name('rstatus')
print(status.text)
```

La salida por pantalla debería corresponder a los elementos deseados

Comment: agradezco sus colobaraciones pero ningun de los metodos descritos sulocionan mi problema ,,,el text result se imprime bien,,,el error da al identificar los otros elemento,,,el error no esta en la impresion si no en la identificacion de los elementos,,siempre de da este tipo de error no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":".rproxy

Comment: Podrías especificar cual es la linea que arroja esa excepción?, intenta hacerlo suelto a ver que resultado trae, por ej `driver.find_element_by_class_name('rproxy').text`

Answer (score 0):

problema resuelta solo era agregarle un time.sleep

```
y=driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@id="results"]').text
time.sleep(5)
x=driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='rproxy']").text
z=driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='rstatus']").text
print(x)
print(y)
print(z)
```

parece que lkos ultimos elementos depende del primero